# Javascript - Controlling image movement at different speeds with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a container and and image inside that container. When the container is not in view - the image must be at translate y 0%. When the container is halfway into the viewport and past halfway - the image must be translate y 50%. The % value must be bound to the position of the container into the viewport (controlled by scrolling). The position of the container also determines the speed the image is being translated at. The problem I'm getting is that when the speed value changes, the image jerks up or down instead of changing the speed from that point onward.

Here is my script:

```
if (wScroll > $(".largeWindow").offset().top - ($(window).height())) {
    var cont = $(".largeWindow");
    var img = $(".coffee2");
    var top = cont.offset().top - cont.height();
    var speed;

    // translate the image within the container
    var moveImage = function() {
      setSpeed();
      var scroll = Math.floor((wScroll - top)) * speed;
      return img.css("transform", "translate(-50%, " + scroll + "%)");
    }

    // get the position of the image within the container
    var getImagePos = function() {
      return img.position().top - img.height()/2;
    }

    var getContainerPos = function() {
      var windowHeight = $(window).height();
      var contPos = Math.floor(cont.offset().top + cont.height()/2) - wScroll;
      return Math.floor(contPos/windowHeight * 100);
    }

    // set the speed the image will be translated at
    var setSpeed = function() {
      if (getContainerPos() < 50) {
        speed = 0;
      }
      else if (getContainerPos() < 60 ) {
        speed = 0.5
      }
      else if (getContainerPos() < 70 ) {
        speed = 0.5
      }
      else {
        speed = 0.8
      }
    }

    getContainerPos();
    moveImage();
    getImagePos();   
    }
```

Here is the sass for the container and image:

```
.largeWindow
  position: relative
  margin: 0 auto
  height: 400px
  width: 400px
  border-radius: 50%
  overflow: hidden
  background:
    image: url(../images/bgTable.jpg)
    size: cover
    repeat: no-repeat
    position: center
    attachment: fixed


  .coffee2
    position: absolute
    height: 200px
    width: 200px
    left: 50%
    transform: translateX(-50%)
    top: - 200px
    background:
      image: url(../images/bgCup.png)
      size: contain
      repeat: no-repeat
      position: center
```